# Bitmap VM memory error

Tags: android

I got an application that take the preview frame and save it as picture. It works perfectly except that after I quit the application and try to run it again, it will always force close and the error is java.lang.out of memory. Anyone knows what the problem? Below is my code and my logcat.

```
public class SymbolCamera extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
Camera camera;
Camera.Parameters params;
SurfaceView surfaceView;
SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
boolean previewing = false;
LayoutInflater controlInflater = null;
TextView tv;
int flag = 0;
//int width, height;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.color_camera_main);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

    getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.UNKNOWN);
    surfaceView = (SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.camerapreview);
    surfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();
    surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
    surfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

    controlInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getBaseContext());
    View viewControl = controlInflater.inflate(R.layout.statistics, null);
    LayoutParams layoutParamsControl = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
    this.addContentView(viewControl, layoutParamsControl);

     tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.info);
     tv.setText("SymbolCamera");
}

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
 MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
 inflater.inflate(R.menu.option_menu_symbol, menu);
 return true;
}

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    Intent intent;
    if(camera != null) 
    {
        camera.setPreviewCallback(null);
        camera.release();
        camera = null;
    }

     switch(item.getItemId())
     {
     case R.id.gps:
         intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), GPSActivity.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
         startActivity(intent);
         finish();
         return true;
     case R.id.color:
         intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ColorCameraActivity.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
         startActivity(intent);
         finish();
         return true;
     }

     return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    if(camera != null) {
        //camera.setPreviewCallback(null);
        camera.release();
        previewing = false;
    }
}

Camera.AutoFocusCallback mAutoFocusCallback = new Camera.AutoFocusCallback() {

    @Override
    public void onAutoFocus(boolean arg0, Camera mCamera) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
};

Camera.PreviewCallback mPreviewCallback = new Camera.PreviewCallback() {

    @Override
    public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera mCamera) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if(flag == 5)
        {
            camera.autoFocus(mAutoFocusCallback);
            camera.setPreviewCallback(null);
        }
        int ARRAY_LENGTH = params.getPreviewSize().width*params.getPreviewSize().height*3/2;
        int argb8888[] = new int[ARRAY_LENGTH]; 
        decodeYUV(argb8888,  data, params.getPreviewSize().width, params.getPreviewSize().height);
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(argb8888, params.getPreviewSize().width, params.getPreviewSize().height, Config.ARGB_8888);

         if(flag == 5) {
            SymbolDetection symDet = new SymbolDetection(bitmap);
             String link =  symDet.run();
             tv.setText(link);
             symDet = null;

         }
         bitmap.recycle();
         flag++;

        /*FileOutputStream fos;
        try {
            fos = new FileOutputStream(String.format(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/testImage/%d.jpg", System.currentTimeMillis()));
            BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
            bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 75, bos);
            bos.flush();
            bos.close();
            fos.close();
            bitmap = null;
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }*/
    }
};

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    /*if(previewing)
    {
        try
        {
            camera.setPreviewDisplay(null);
            camera.setPreviewCallback(null);
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        camera.stopPreview();
        camera.release();
        previewing = false;
    }*/

    if(camera != null)
    {
        try {
            tv.setText("start camera");
            //params.setPreviewSize(width, height);
            camera.setPreviewCallback(mPreviewCallback);
            camera.setParameters(params);
            camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
            camera.startPreview();
            previewing = true;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    camera = Camera.open();
    params = camera.getParameters();
    //width = params.getPreviewSize().width;
    //height = params.getPreviewSize().height;

}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(previewing && camera != null)
    {
        try {
            camera.setPreviewCallback(null);
            camera.setPreviewDisplay(null);
            camera.stopPreview();
            camera.release();
            camera = null;

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    previewing = false;
}


// decode Y, U, and V values on the YUV 420 buffer described as YCbCr_422_SP by Android 
// David Manpearl 081201 
public void decodeYUV(int[] out, byte[] fg, int width, int height)
        throws NullPointerException, IllegalArgumentException {
    int sz = width * height;
    if (out == null)
        throw new NullPointerException("buffer out is null");
    if (out.length < sz)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("buffer out size " + out.length
                + " < minimum " + sz);
    if (fg == null)
        throw new NullPointerException("buffer 'fg' is null");
    if (fg.length < sz)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("buffer fg size " + fg.length
                + " < minimum " + sz * 3 / 2);
    int i, j;
    int Y, Cr = 0, Cb = 0;
    for (j = 0; j < height; j++) {
        int pixPtr = j * width;
        final int jDiv2 = j >> 1;
        for (i = 0; i < width; i++) {
            Y = fg[pixPtr];
            if (Y < 0)
                Y += 255;
            if ((i & 0x1) != 1) {
                final int cOff = sz + jDiv2 * width + (i >> 1) * 2;
                Cb = fg[cOff];
                if (Cb < 0)
                    Cb += 127;
                else
                    Cb -= 128;
                Cr = fg[cOff + 1];
                if (Cr < 0)
                    Cr += 127;
                else
                    Cr -= 128;
            }
            int R = Y + Cr + (Cr >> 2) + (Cr >> 3) + (Cr >> 5);
            if (R < 0)
                R = 0;
            else if (R > 255)
                R = 255;
            int G = Y - (Cb >> 2) + (Cb >> 4) + (Cb >> 5) - (Cr >> 1)
                    + (Cr >> 3) + (Cr >> 4) + (Cr >> 5);
            if (G < 0)
                G = 0;
            else if (G > 255)
                G = 255;
            int B = Y + Cb + (Cb >> 1) + (Cb >> 2) + (Cb >> 6);
            if (B < 0)
                B = 0;
            else if (B > 255)
                B = 255;
            out[pixPtr++] = 0xff000000 + (B << 16) + (G << 8) + R;
        }
    }

}
}
```

logcat:

```
10-13 18:22:29.017: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(32260): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-13 18:22:29.017: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(32260): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
10-13 18:22:29.017: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(32260):     at    android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
10-13 18:22:29.017: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(32260):     at   android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:513)
10-13 18:22:29.017: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(32260):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:533)
10-13 18:22:29.017: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(32260):     at com.augmented.reality.SymbolCamera$2.onPreviewFrame(SymbolCamera.java:129)
10-13 18:22:29.017: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(32260):     at android.hardware.Camera$EventHandler.handleMessage(Camera.java:547)
10-13 18:22:29.017: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(32260):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-13 18:22:29.017: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(32260):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
10-13 18:22:29.017: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(32260):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3703)
10-13 18:22:29.017: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(32260):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-13 18:22:29.017: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(32260):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
10-13 18:22:29.017: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(32260):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
10-13 18:22:29.017: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(32260):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
10-13 18:22:29.017: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(32260):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Check the "related" bar on the right of this site. This question gets asked multiple times a day here. It's all documented - including all the ways to solve this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android: Strange out of memory issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/477572/android-strange-out-of-memory-issue)

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem so I wrote special Bitmap Manager which you can find [here](http://code.google.com/p/bitmap-gc/)